When localization commutes with arbitrary intersection of ideals
For a commutative ring with identity we know that in general localization does not commute with arbitrary intersection of ideals. I am looking for a paper that considers equivalent condition(s) for rings that do have this property. (I have seen such an article but I cannot find it right now.)

Hello!  Welcome to MO.  To clarify, are you asking, for which commutative rings $R$ does one have $S^{-1} \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} I_\lambda = \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda}  S^{-1} I_\lambda$ for every collection ${I_\lambda: \lambda \in \Lambda}$ of ideals of $R$ and every multiplicative subset $S$ of $R$?
